# Running a custom macro from after insert macro

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I created a function in VBA called `insertSeats()`.

I then created a custom macro within access that has `RunCode insertSeats()`.

How can I call this custom macro through the After Insert macro trigger? I tried RunDataMacro and that does not call it.

Comment: After Insert macro trigger?  When are you trying to run this?  And if it's just a function, why not just run the function instead of the macro?

Comment: I agree with @Johnny Bones - just set the Form 'After Insert' Event property  to 'insertSeats()'.   If you have your heart set on running a macro, again change the 'After Insert' property to 'MyMacroName'

Comment: What if I am not using a form? And just want it to trigger after insert on a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. The `After Insert`/`After Update` etc. event macros are designed to run in JET not Access. As a result what you program into them cannot depend on VBA code because VBA cannot run in your database only in Access. This is important for when someone is changing date from outside Access (say some C# app that also looks at your database). You want your table events to work no matter what front end is attached to your data. You are stuck doing some very simple things as a result.

Comment: not what I wanted to hear but thanks...So I am stuck with using forms?

Comment: You are stuck using a canonical form. And if make your data available in another front end you will need to move this same logic to there too.